# Swift Decodable: how to transform one of values during decoding?

Tags: ios, json, swift, decoder, codable

Be default, `Decodable` protocol makes translation of JSON values to object values with no change. But sometimes you need to transform value during json decoding, for example, in JSON you get `{id = "id10"}` but in your class instance you need to put number `10` into property `id` (or into even property with different name).

You can implement method `init(from:)` where you can do what you want with any of the values, for example:

```
public required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    latitude = try container.decode(Double.self, forKey:.latitude)
    longitude = try container.decode(Double.self, forKey: .longitude)
    // and for example there i can transform string "id10" to number 10
    // and put it into desired field
}
```

Thats sounds great for me, but what if i want to change value **just for one** of the JSON fields and left all my other 20 fields with no change? In case of `init(from:)` i should manually get and put values for every of 20 fields of my class! After years of objC coding it's intuitive for me to first call super's implementation of `init(from:)` and then make changes just to some fields, but how i can achieve such effect with Swift and `Decodable` protocol?

Comment: Compare [Swift 4 JSON Decodable simplest way to decode type change](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44594652/2976878) – one option would be a wrapper type.

Comment: I looked to code snippet by your link. Seems i have to implement `init(from:)` method for all the properties anyway?

Comment: No, the first two examples in my answer using `StringCodableMap` didn't implement `init(from:)`; they relied on the auto-generated `Codable` conformance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently you are forced to fully implement the `encode` and `decode` methods if you want to change the parsing of even a single property.

Some future version of Swift Codable will likely allow case-by-case handling of each property's encoding and decoding. But that Swift feature work is non-trivial and hasn't been prioritized yet:

> Regardless, the goal is to likely offer a strongly-typed solution that allows you to do this on a case-by-case basis with out falling off the "cliff" into having to implement all of `encode(to:` and `init(from:` for the benefit of one property; the solution is likely nontrivial and would require a lot of API discussion to figure out how to do well, hence why we haven't been able to do this yet.
>
> - Itai Ferber, lead developer on Swift 4 Codable
>
> https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-5249?focusedCommentId=32638

Comment: Thanks. Interesting. "falling off the cliff" - excellent describing phrase :) Well, at least I glad to hear they considered the problem.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a `lazy var`. The downside being that you still have to provide a list of keys and you can't declare your model a constant:

```
struct MyModel: Decodable {
    lazy var id: Int = {
        return Int(_id.replacingOccurrences(of: "id", with: ""))!
    }()
    private var _id: String

    var latitude: CGFloat
    var longitude: CGFloat

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case latitude, longitude
        case _id = "id"
    }
}
```

Example:

```
let json = """
{
    "id": "id10",
    "latitude": 1,
    "longitude": 1
}
""".data(using: .utf8)!

// Can't use a `let` here
var m = try JSONDecoder().decode(MyModel.self, from: json)
print(m.id)
```

Comment: Thanks! It could be a workaround in some cases if one can accept a violation of the model's immutability.