# Convert string JSON response to a boolean using Swift 4 Decodable

Tags: ios, json, swift, swift4, decodable

I'm refactoring some projects where I'd previously used third-party JSON parsers and I've encountered a goofy site that returns a boolean as a string.

This is the relevant snippet from the JSON response:

```
{
    "delay": "false",
    /* a bunch of other keys*/
}
```

My struct for Decoding looks like this:

```
struct MyJSONStruct: Decodable {
  let delay: Bool
  // the rest of the keys
}
```

How would I convert the string returned in the JSON response into a Bool to match my struct in Swift 4? While [this post](http://benscheirman.com/2017/06/ultimate-guide-to-json-parsing-with-swift-4/) was helpful, I can't figure out how to turn a string response into a boolean value.

Comment: override `init(decoder: Decoder)` and manually handle ALL of the decoding. I say all because you can't optionally decode some fields and not others.

Comment: Ouch. I've got ~20 keys with some nested structs, all for one boolean.

Comment: Compare https://stackoverflow.com/q/44594652/2976878

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Basically you have to write a custom initializer but if there are many *good* keys but only one to map from a type to another a computed property might be useful

```
struct MyJSONStruct: Decodable {
   var delay: String
   // the rest of the keys

   var boolDelay : Bool {
       get { return delay == "true" }
       set { delay = newValue ? "true" : "false" }
   }
}
```

Comment: Oh! That's brilliant! I'd rather add 3 lines of code than a custom initializer. Thank you!

Comment: @LeoDabus I changed the `let` to a `var`. Thanks again for this simple workaround.

Answer (score 1):

you need to set the boolEncoding: .literal in the URLEncoding initializer.

```
boolEncoding: .literal
```