# Custom intialiser on Primitive types for JSONDecoder

Tags: swift, jsondecoder

How do I customise the behaviour of JSONDecoder for `primitive` types like Int, Bool?

Here is the problem:

- Backend cannot be relied upon for types. Eg: Bool can come as true/false or "true"/"false"(bool can come wrapped in double quotes)
- We have at least 300 Codable structs having average 15 properties in them and writing decoding logic for all of them is cumbersome. Also the logic remains more or less same hence the code has become repetitive

Hence, I am looking for a solution such that if there is a `Type mismatch` then primitive types should be able to handle it and if not then it should be set to `nil` if that type is Optional.

---

### I tried multiple approaches for this

#### 1. Having Wrapper on all the primitive types and handling the decoding logic. Below is an example of wrapper on Bool

```
struct SafeBool: Codable {
    private var bool: Bool?

    public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        if let b = try? container.decode(Bool.self) {
            self.bool = b
        } else if let string = try? container.decode(String.self) {
            if string.lowercased() == "true" {
                self.bool = true
            } else if string.lowercased() == "false" {
                self.bool = false
            } else {
                throw Error()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This, although solves the problem, but creats unnecessary confusion among fellow developers as Wrapped types do not come out as naturally as the Native ones. Also the value cannot be accessed directly (it always need xyz.bool) to extract the raw value

#### 2. Create a new protocol inherited from Decodable and subclass `JSONDecoder`

```
protocol KKDecodable: Decodable {
    init(decoder1: Decoder)
}

extension Bool: KKDecodable {
    init(decoder1: Decoder) {
     // Logic for creating Bool from different types
    }
}

class JSONDecoder1: JSONDecoder {
    func decode<T>(_ type: T.Type, from data: Data) throws -> T where T : KKDecodable {
         // Some code that would invoke `init(decoder1: Decoder)`
         // which is defined in `KKDecodable`
    }
}
```

I was not able to write working code using this method

Comment: How about this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/46850257/562298 (Create a custom wrapper for your custom type, and then adding a computed property that calls through to xyz.bool, so devs don't need to be confused.)

Comment: Ya. That is the solution that I have implemented right now. But it has some downsides. 1. All the developers need to use wrapper types, which does not look intuitive 2. All variables would need extra function to extract the actual value.

Comment: *Backend cannot be relied upon for types.* Why? That's ridiculous. The backend is supposed to make the effort for perfomance reasons, not the frontend.

Comment: I suppose `JSONSerialization` doesn't work in your case?

Comment: Hey. The answer works. It's just that I was looking for a solution that will not involve modifying the existing Codable types. As mentioned in the question, there are huge number of Codable types. However, I think your answer is the best one can do for the mentioned problem

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Property Wrapper

You can use property wrapper. Imagine this as an example:

```
@propertyWrapper
struct SomeKindOfBool: Decodable {
    var wrappedValue: Bool?
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        if let stringifiedValue = try? container.decode(String.self) {
            switch stringifiedValue.lowercased() {
            case "false": wrappedValue = false
            case "true": wrappedValue = true
            default: wrappedValue = nil
            }
        } else {
            wrappedValue = try? container.decode(Bool.self)
        }
    }
}
```

## Usage

```
struct MyType: Decodable {
    @SomeKindOfBool var someKey: Bool?
}
```

You can use `someKey` value like a normal `Bool` now:

#### Test:

```
let jsonData = """
[
 { "someKey": "something else" },
 { "someKey": "true" },
 { "someKey": true }
]
""".data(using: .utf8)!

let decodedJSON = try! JSONDecoder().decode([MyType].self, from: jsonData)

for decodedType in decodedJSON {
    print(decodedType.someKey)
}
```

#### Result:

> nil
>
> Optional(true)
>
> Optional(true)

---

You can do similar for other situations and also any other type you need. Also **note that** I have changed the code to match your needs, but you can use the more compatible version that I posted as a [gist here in GitHub](https://gist.github.com/MojtabaHs/a8c19aea78c01ffc3063745dbbc10df1)

Comment: Hm, it seems this solution doesn't work for non-existing keys. I'd like to decode such keys to nil. When using the property wrapper, a `Swift.DecodingError.keyNotFound` is thrown instead.

Comment: Yep, you shod change the code for supporting optionals too. I had that but not on the gist. You can ask a question so The community and I can answer that specific question there.

Comment: Thanks, I've posted a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/69978668/235297