# How can I use @propertyWrapper for Decodable with optional keys?

Tags: swift, decodable, property-wrapper

I'm using a [property wrapper](https://gist.github.com/MojtabaHs/a8c19aea78c01ffc3063745dbbc10df1) to decode the strings "true" and "false" as Booleans. I also want to make the key optional. So if the key is missing from the JSON, it should be decoded as nil. Unfortunately, adding the property wrapper breaks this and a `Swift.DecodingError.keyNotFound` is thrown instead.

```
@propertyWrapper
struct SomeKindOfBool: Decodable {
    var wrappedValue: Bool?
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        if let stringifiedValue = try? container.decode(String.self) {
            switch stringifiedValue.lowercased() {
            case "false": wrappedValue = false
            case "true": wrappedValue = true
            default: wrappedValue = nil
            }
        } else {
            wrappedValue = try? container.decode(Bool.self)
        }
    }
}

public struct MyType: Decodable {
    @SomeKindOfBool var someKey: Bool?
}

let jsonData = """
[
 { "someKey": true },
 { "someKey": "false" },
 {}
]
""".data(using: .utf8)!

let decodedJSON = try! JSONDecoder().decode([MyType].self, from: jsonData)

for decodedType in decodedJSON {
    print(decodedType.someKey ?? "nil")
}
```

Any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: @SPatel this service doesn't use property wrappers so it's not really helpful.

Comment: What happens if you change the type of someKey to be non-optional?

Comment: Same error. And then I could no longer differentiate between false and nil (aka not existing).

Comment: Ok, I tried running your code and it fails on the last entry in your json, `{}`, which I am not sure what it's supposed to be? And next time you post an error message then post the full message.

Comment: Have you tried with `decodeIfPresent`instead?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson indeed, it fails on the last `{}`. It should set `someKey` to nil since it's an Optional.

Comment: But it doesn’t matter if someKey is optional since that mean that the value is optional, here we have neither key nor value. So the last {} means an empty object but nothing about its type.

Comment: If I implement decode method in MyType then it does not forward control to PropertyWrapper's decoding method. In some cases we are decoding properties manually using container and custom keys. Any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The synthesized code for `init(from:)` normally uses `decodeIfPresent` when the type is optional. However, property wrappers are always non-optional and only may use an optional as their underlying value. That's why the synthesizer always uses the normal `decode` which fails if the key isn't present (a [good writeup in the Swift Forums](https://forums.swift.org/t/using-property-wrappers-with-codable/29804/5)).

I solved the problem by using the excellent [CodableWrappers package](https://github.com/GottaGetSwifty/CodableWrappers#Optionals):

```
public struct NonConformingBoolStaticDecoder: StaticDecoder {
    
    public static func decode(from decoder: Decoder) throws -> Bool {
        if let stringValue = try? String(from: decoder) {
            switch stringValue.lowercased() {
            case "false", "no", "0": return false
            case "true", "yes", "1": return true
            default:
                throw DecodingError.valueNotFound(self, DecodingError.Context(
                    codingPath: decoder.codingPath,
                    debugDescription: "Expected true/false, yes/no or 0/1 but found \(stringValue) instead"))
            }
        } else {
            return try Bool(from: decoder)
        }
    }
}

typealias NonConformingBoolDecoding = DecodingUses<NonConformingBoolStaticDecoder>
```

Then I can define my decodable struct like this:

```
public struct MyType: Decodable {
    @OptionalDecoding<NonConformingBoolDecoding> var someKey: Bool?
}
```